# Prove $x^2+4y^2<1$ given $x^3 + y^3 = x-y$ and x and y are positive real numbers. (Using AM-GM)

Tags: inequality, contest-math, a.m.-g.m.-inequality

I have tried the following and other methods, however I haven't been able to solve this. I would very much appreciate if someone can point me in the right direction on how this can be solved. 
$x-y=(x+y)(x^2 -xy+y^2)$
$(x+y)((x-y)^2-xy) = (x-y)$
$(x-y)[(x-y)(x+y) -1] - xy(x+y) = 0$
However this does not seem to lead anywhere.
This question is supposed to be solved with AM-GM however I haven't been able to apply it so far in any way which will lead to the inequality.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Prove the inequality $x^2+4y^2&lt;1$ when $x-y=x^3+y^3$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3192154/prove-the-inequality-x24y21-when-x-y-x3y3) - found using an [Approach0 search](https://approach0.xyz/search/?q=OR%20content%3A%24x%5E2%2B4y%5E2%5Clt%201%24%2C%20OR%20content%3A%24x%5E3%2By%5E3%3Dx-y%24%2C%20OR%20content%3Apositive%20real&p=1). Note the [accepted answer](/a/3192173) there uses AM-GM, as you requested. There are also other duplicates on this site, e.g., [Inequality $a^2+4b^2<1$.](/q/3386240), as well as multiple AoPS threads, e.g., ...

Comment: (cont.) [Inequalities](https://artofproblemsolving.com/community/c4h1916449p13134604), [Equation x^3 + y^3 = x - y implies x^2 + 4y^2 < 1](https://artofproblemsolving.com/community/c6h247770p1359460), [Positive real numbers](https://artofproblemsolving.com/community/c6h1515902p9028212), etc. Last, but not least, welcome to Math SE.